# If I run react-native packager on port 9999 how do I tell the IOS simulator that that is the port to listen to?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Probably will need to know how to fix this for **Android** as well.

I don't see any answers for this in help:

```
$ react-native run-ios --help 

react-native run-ios [options]
builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator

Options:

-h, --help               output usage information
--simulator [string]     Explicitly set simulator to use
--scheme [string]        Explicitly set Xcode scheme to use
--project-path [string]  Path relative to project root where the Xcode project (.xcodeproj) lives. The default is 'ios'.
--device [string]        Explicitly set device to use by name
--udid [string]          Explicitly set device to use by udid
--config [string]        Path to the CLI configuration file
```

I'd like to run my react-packager on a different port because there is an agent listening on 8081 that I probably shouldn't kill.

I'm starting the app with

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --port 9999
```

Which results in:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/collumj/research/indraEight/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Script-006B79A01A781F38006873D1.sh
```

And the app won't start (instant crash). Killing the process that is listening on 8081 and starting the app will result in `BUILD SUCCEEDED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change that you have to do this:

- Open the **Developer menu**
- Select **Dev Settings**
- Finally select **Debug server host & port for develop**

That's all, good luck

Comment: Cmd-D? What does "Open menu option" mean? I don't see Dev Settings anywhere in the menus. BTW I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Sorry I found my mistake, it works on android but for ios according to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) you have to change this line `jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];` in **AppDelegate.m** file

Comment: Wow that seems weird. I can change the port on the command line on one side but I have to find/edit a .m file on the other side?